# Check browser cookie disabled

Tags: asp.net, cookies, umbraco, httpmodule

We are using an Http Module. In the http module we are setting a cookie. After that in the page we are trying to take the value from cookie.

So when we are requesting a page, first the code inside http module will execute and it will set the cookie and then the value can be taken from cookie in the page load of the page.

But while debugging the code in Visual studio, we found that if **browser cookie is disabled**, then in the httpModule it will try to set the cookie and after that in the page load if we check the request object, it is showing the cookie set from the httpModule.

Is this a correct behavior? I want to know whether cookie is disabled in this case. If it is diabled i want to take another value from db. But it always showing the value in cookie.

Can anyone please suggest a method to get whether cookie is disabled or not.

We are using the httpModule in an Umbraco site.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a cookie and then do a redirect to check if that cookie exists if it does then you know cookies are enabled if not then cookies are not enabled. Here is a good example.

http://www.primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article54.aspx

Comment: This is only useful if you need to heavily restrict access to your site if the client can't accept cookies. What you are suggesting is that if a client can't accept cookies they are continuously redirected to a single page. For example, this would mean that a search engine would never be able to crawl the site.

Comment: Good point, out of curiosity what would be  a better solution ?